# Why does $\mathbb{P}(x)=\frac{3}{x^2\pi^2}$ have no expectation?

Tags: probability, summation

The textbook answer to $\mathbb{E}(X)$ for $\{\mathbb{P}(X=x)=\frac{3}{x^2\pi^2}, x\in \mathbb{Z}\setminus 0 \}$ is it doesn't exist because of subtraction of $\infty$. But in my calculation I find that $\mathbb{E}(X)=\sum_{-\infty}^{-1}{\frac{3}{x\pi^2}}+\sum_{1}^{\infty}{\frac{3}{x\pi^2}}=\frac{3}{\pi^2}\sum_1^\infty{1/x}-\sum_1^\infty{1/x}=0$. What's wrong with factorizing the negative out?

Comment: WolframAlpha says that the sum diverges. Note that for a sum $\sum_{x=-\infty}^\infty f(x)$, we say that the sum converges if $\lim_{i\rightarrow -\infty}\lim_{j\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{x=-i}^j f(x)$ is convergent. But $\lim_{j\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{x=-i}^j \frac{3}{x\pi^2}$ is divergent for any $i$.

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(x)$? Don't you mean $\mathbb{P}(X = x)$?

Comment: Is it $\frac3{x^2\pi^2}$ or $\frac3{x\pi^2}$???

Comment: Also note that $\Bbb{E}[\ |X|\ ] = +\infty$

Comment: It's not true that $\sum 1/j-\sum1/j=0$. Because $\sum 1/j$ does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We define $\mathbb{E}[X] := \mathbb{E}[X^+]-\mathbb{E}[X^-]$ where $X^+$ is the positive and $X^-$ the negative part of $X$, whenever the two expectations exist.

But as you probably (unconsciously) noted, $E[X^+] = E[X^-] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3}{n\pi^2} = \infty$, so $\mathbb{E}[X]$ is undefined.